# Can not find element in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use an Angular directive for input file with file type, but input variable is undefined.

```
angular.directive("ngUpload", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        template : '<input id="fileInput" name="file" type="file" class="ng-hide" multiple><md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-raised md-primary"> Choose Files </md-button>',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var input = element.find('#fileInput');
            var button = element.find('#uploadButton');

            if (input.length && button.length) {
                button.click((e) => input.click());
            }
        },
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite) jqLite's find is limited to lookup by tag name.

So you can either include jQuery (before angular.js) to retrieve the element by id or use an alternative way to grab a hold of the input.

You don't even need an id selector since there's only one input element in your template, so this should work:

```
var input = element.find('input');
```

Also, `directive` is declared on a module, not on the global angular object.

Lastly, don't prefix your own directives with `ng-` as they may clash with (future) angular core directives.

A more complete example:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive("customUpload", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        template : '<input id="fileInput" name="file" type="file" class="ng-hide" multiple><md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-raised md-primary"> Choose Files </md-button>',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var input = element.find('input');
            var button = element.find('md-button');

            if (input.length && button.length) {
                button.click((e) => input.click());
            }
        },
    };
});
```